# Whenever a mail is sent from Outlook 2010 that mail should move to dedicated folder in Outlook, using VBA/Macros

Tags: vba

I have already wrote a code where the when ever a email comes from a definite email ID to outlook my ID it gets sent to anothee email address automatically by using one rule.

Now I have to add one feature. This mail which is sent is also saved in a dedicated folder other than sent items. All this in one script.

This my current script where only the mail goes automatically. Now I need help to add the dedicated folder feature.

```
Sub Project_1()
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set objItem = GetCurrentItem()
Set objMail = objItem.Forward
objMail.To = "inbox@email.com"
objMail.Display
objMail.Send
Set objItem = Nothing
Set objMail = Nothing
End Sub
Function GetCurrentItem() As Object
Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
Set objApp = Application
On Error Resume Next
Select Case TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow)
Case "Explorer"
Set GetCurrentItem = _
objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
Case "Inspector"
Set GetCurrentItem = _
objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
Case Else
End Select
End Function
```

I am very new to VBA.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: So, all you need is to save a mail item in a folder other than "sent items"? Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: You can avoid VBA entirely by using [Outlook's rules](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Manage-email-messages-by-using-rules-50307363-0e79-4f6a-95c0-04b922a2ff13?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB), to manage your mailbox.

Comment: Thats true i need save all the sent items in the dedicated folder by adding some thing to this code. It should run automatically.

Comment: Hi @DavidG .  Any help on this. I am waiting for your reply.

Comment: @Avi: I am trying to understand your goal. Is my assumption correct?

Comment: Hi @DavidG: I am trying to call the script through rule. When an email comes with a specif subject from a specif source, it will be forward to another person in plain text format, and then it has to be moved from my Inbox to another folder in outlook.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Outlook VBA Save Copy Sent Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22867701/outlook-vba-save-copy-sent-item)

Answer (score 0):

As @destination-data stated above, the whole task will be much easier through outlooks rules.

[This article](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/1162-outlook-auto-move-email-to-folder.html) is a step-by-step guide on how to set rules for moving certain mails based on conditions. Additionally you can easily add a "forward" rule, since all your desired functionality is already implemented into outlook and one should avoid rewriting existing tools.

According to your description, this should accomplish the exact same thing as intended by your code.