# How do I use ItemAdd on the Sent Items folder?

Tags: vba, email, outlook

This question looks like it should have been answered here:
[Outlook VBA Save Copy Sent Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22867701/outlook-vba-save-copy-sent-item)

I am unable to find the referenced "Items.ItemAdd" event amongst the list of events in the VB Editor for Outlook 2016.

Application.ItemSend is located in "ThisOutLookSession". The script I came up with looks 90% similar to the one posted in the original question and I have the same problem. The mail item is saved in it's pre-send condition.

I can't use "MailItem.SaveSentMessageFolder" as I am trying to move the sent mail to a PST.

The Event is explained here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/items-itemadd-event-outlook

In case someone asks "Why not use the AutoArchive Function?", my organization has some terrible group policies set up for both Sent Items and AutoArchive. I can't wade through the mess to get AutoArchive for sent items set up.

Comment: So what is not working in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Work with [Items.ItemAdd Event (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/items-itemadd-event-outlook)*

*Example*

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Inbox  As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
    Set Items = Inbox.Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.mailitem Then
'        code to copy the sent Item here
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I was missing the point of object_ in object_ItemAdd was a user provided object (and thus ItemAdd was an event that can come with that object). Sorry for the terrible explanation. Anyway, thanks.