# Save just sent emails. Not a SentItems event listener

Tags: vba, email, outlook

Outlook won't receive VBA a sent email until the macro sending the email completes.

If I use wait, sleep, while loops or anything else, the email will not be received. I don't want a SentItems event listener because I want specific emails saved to the folder, not all.

The issue is the delay between sending the email with VBA and it appearing in my Sent Items box.
If I SaveAs before waiting, the email that is saved is the previous email.
If I try to wait, the Sent Items folder never updates.

I had it running at another company but no longer remember how.

I use a macro to send an email and do other tasks. I would then like to grab the email I just sent and save it to a folder using VBA.
If I try to capture it or wait to receive it, my code never finishes. All solutions in forums are a Sent Item listener / Inbox event listener, but I don't need that, I know which emails to trigger it on.

Comment: Sample code might help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save Copy of Sent Item in a specific folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22867701/save-copy-of-sent-item-in-a-specific-folder)

Comment: @dbmitch, the code is on a work computer. I can't provide it without typing it all out again. I have found a way to do it, but not how I did it in the past.

Comment: @niton That is an event listener, it doesn't really help except as it was the thing I was trying to avoid but I did end up using the event listener.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [NameSpace.SendAndReceive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.sendandreceive) method which initiates immediate delivery of all undelivered messages submitted in the current session, and immediate receipt of mail for all accounts in the current profile. Note, calling the `SendAndReceive` method is asynchronous. `SendAndReceive` provides the programmatic equivalent to the `Send/Receive All` command that is available when you click `Tools` and then `Send/Receive`.

If you don't need to synchronize all objects, you can use the [SyncObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.syncobjects) collection object to select specific objects. For more information, see `NameSpace.SyncObjects`.

In your VBA code you may also consider using the [DoEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doevents-function) function which yields execution so that the operating system can process other events. `DoEvents` passes control to the operating system. Control is returned after the operating system has finished processing the events in its queue and all keys in the `SendKeys` queue have been sent (if any).

`DoEvents` is most useful for simple things like allowing a user to cancel a process after it has started, for example a search for a file.

Answer (score 0):

One way or another, you'd need to wait for some event to fire, be that `Items.ItemAdd` on the Sent Items folder, or `SyncObject.SyncEnd` on the `SyncObject` - message submission is asynchronous, so no amount of `sleep` or while loops would help you. You cannot just stop your VBA script and resume it when the message is actually sent since your code is running on the main Outlook thread - if your script pauses, so does Outlook.

Comment: Yep, I somehow did it in the past where I didn't need an event listener but was able to immediately save the sent mailitem before it showed in the sent inbox. I have found a workaround. Your comment did confirm to me that I probably won't find my solution again. Thank you

Comment: You can save it as any moment prior to calling Send, but it will be in the draft (unsent) state and the sender properties won't be populated. Otherwise `Items.ItemAdd` event on the Sent Items folder is your first chance - there are no other workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Solution, not the solution or used in the past but I settled.

1. Basically just the event listener solution that everyone in all the forums suggest. I created a separate folder in my Sent Items and use myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder to set that folder for the VBA sent items.. I send the emails only to that folder and I added the listener to only that folder. This allows me to separate the Sent items and this specific VBA sent emails and then to save them automatically. I am still looking for a way to save the sent Mail Item before the Sent Item Inbox shows it, but I have given up at this point. Thanks for everyone's help. If I find the better answer, I will try to post it along with the code.